# CORS Issue when upgrading to Angularfire2 v5

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire2

I'm trying to update one of my projects to Angularfire2 version 5.0.0-rc.3 from v4, but now it's throwing a CORS error when I'm developing in the Chrome browser:

> Failed to load
>   https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1beta1.Firestore/Listen/channel?gsessionid....:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Can someone tell me why this is an issue with v5 of Angularfire2, when it worked fine with v4?

I don't want to set up a proxy server to get around this.